# When viewing a post's revisions history from a review queue, make the "Return to Question/Answer" link less unintuitive

Tags: feature-request, review, hyperlinks, revisions-list

I was in the *First questions* review queue and found that when clicking to view the revisions list, the "Return to Question" link was a bit unintuitive (since I didn't get to the revision history page from viewing the question page).

It might be useful to keep that link around, but just re-label it to say something like "Go to Question".

The same applies when reviewing answers in *First answers* and other queues: the "Return to Answer" link is confusing when the revision history is accessed from the review queue.

While browsers usually have history functionality to go back to the previous page, it might be desirable for the same reasons that motivated having the "Return to [Question/Answer]" link become a "Return to Review" link.